# Changeable HTML dropdown menu in javascript localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, dropdown

I have made a basic dropdown menu whose options are created when the user inputs text in a text field and presses a *Create Option* button.

Need help on storing dropdown menu with all the options created by the user in localStorage when the user clicks the *Save* button.

and so doing that when the user reloads the page the options created by the user will still be visible? With pure Javascript ?

My code so far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<div id="name">
  <select id="sel"></select>
  <input type="text" class="auto-save" id="inputname">
  <button id="button" onclick="newnamefunc(); document.getElementById('inputname').value='';">Create Option</button><button id="save">Save</button></div>
<script>
  const saved = localStorage.getItem('select')
  const sel = document.getElementById('sel')
  if (document.getElementById('sel')) {
    sel.innerHTML = saved
  }


  function newnamefunc() {
    const inputval = document.getElementById('inputname').value;
    const createname = document.createElement("option");
    const namevalue = document.createTextNode(inputval);
    createname.appendChild(namevalue);

    const element = document.getElementById("sel");
    element.appendChild(createname);
  }
  /html>
```

Any and all help appreciated.

Comment: Where's your save button / function? What have you tried so far? localStorage only supports storing text / strings, so you need to account for that.

Answer (score 0):

Would this help? I set the `innerHTML` of the select to the localStorage and updated the select when the window loaded.

```js
const saved = localStorage.getItem('select')

window.onload = function (){
    document.getElementById('sel').innerHTML = saved
      
};

function newnamefunc() {
  const inputval = document.getElementById('inputname').value;
  const createname = document.createElement("option");
  const namevalue = document.createTextNode(inputval);
  createname.appendChild(namevalue);

  const element = document.getElementById("sel");
  element.appendChild(createname);
}

function save(){
  var select = document.getElementById("sel").innerHTML;
  localStorage.setItem("select", select);

}
```

```html
<div id="name">
        <select id="sel"></select>
        <input type="text" class="auto-save" id="inputname">
        <button id="button" onclick="newnamefunc(); document.getElementById('inputname').value='';">Create Option</button>
        <button id="save" onclick="save()">Save</button>
      </div>
```

Comment: @vedant12355 Glad to help :)